# dual boot 14.04 / 17.04 lost grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I had ubuntu14.04LTS running and installed ubuntu 17.04 making a partition. So I got 2 choices at startup. This worked fine until a couple of weeks. I assume after a 14.04 update, the initial menu (grub?) disapeared, and notebook starts directly on 14.04.

I tryed boot-repair with this result: GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again. Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.

Things from there are too complicated in forums, I am not an expert, just a user.

Partitions are still there with all the content.

bootinfo from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25575784/

Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: You have installed in UEFI mode (correct) but booted Boot Repair in Legacy (incorrect twice, Boot Repair isn't even for this cases). Now: 1. You can boot either from the UEFI boot settings, probably, or 2. Just do `sudo update-grub` and it should find both again and recreate the boot entries (if you prefer 17.04's Grub to be in charge, then boot it and do the same).

Comment: You have an UEFI system with UEFI installs. But if Boot-Repair is asking for a bios_grub partition then you must have booted the Ubuntu live installer in BIOS mode as that would then want to install a BIOS boot version of grub. Only boot system & any live installer in UEFI mode. Many with Secure Boot have to specifically allow USB boot in UEFI as that is not considered "Secure".  Probably easiest to boot in UEFI mode, add Boot-Repair and in advanced mode do the total reinstall of grub.

Comment: @MichaelBay I did sudo update-grub, many lines about found things, but still boots directly to 14.04

Comment: @oldfred I think I am in UEFI mode now, how can I check that without going to BIOS menu? and boot-repair gives me this "GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition" message

Comment: @oldfred  recent bootinfo http://paste.ubuntu.com/25589056/

Comment: I just filed bug report in Boot-Repair. You have UEFI installs, and Boot-Repair says you even have UEFI Secure boot on. Adding bios_grub partition and installing the BIOS boot version of grub will not work. You need UEFI version. If you boot your 14.04 install you can see your /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu folder. And in it is a 3 line grub.cfg. It will have UUID and partition number of 14.04 install and you should be able to change to UUID & partition for new install. Back up file first just in case you make a typo and have to restore old version.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you. I am sorry not to be capable to follow you. Almost user level new to ubuntu. Maybe I can manage to locate de cfg file but the rest... I can't get what does "change to UUID & partition for new install" mean.

Comment: by the way, I boot 14.04 as it's where it goes and I have no chance.

Comment: Post these in first post and preserve formatting. `cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`

Answer (score 2):

Your grub.cfg should be this:

```
cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
search.fs_uuid 94ce33db-7654-4e3e-a9be-a3063bb155cf root hd0,gpt4 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

You get UUID from this(I got it from the Boot-Repair report).

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
```

And you want to change first line to UUID of sda4 & gpt4 to gpt6, copy & paste UUID from above command. Orcopy this line & paste. Best to also add # to existing line as first char changing to a comment. Then easier to revert if required.

```
search.fs_uuid 00aee336-b9ae-4c75-8edc-a19adb0b5451  root hd0,gpt6

sudo nano /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
```

It should end up like this:

```
search.fs_uuid 00aee336-b9ae-4c75-8edc-a19adb0b5451  root hd0,gpt6
#search.fs_uuid 94ce33db-7654-4e3e-a9be-a3063bb155cf root hd0,gpt4 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Comment: how do you copy and paste here terminal lines in their original format?

Comment: 4 spaces make a command & one of the icons will make multiple lines as commands by indenting them the 4 spaces.

Comment: Ok. I will study the procedure and try. Not a simple thing to me.

Comment: should just be a copy & paste. nano is old style editor, you have to use arrow keys to move pointer, but still can copy & paste.

Comment: SOLVED !!!! Thank you @oldfred... if you can, tell me what whe did....

Comment: We just changed which grub.cfg to use. When UEFI boots, then grubx4.efi loads and finds the 3 line grub.cfg in the ESP - efi system partition to find the full grub config in your install. You could have done the same by totally reinstalling grub which would then create a new grub.cfg in the ESP. The configfile is a load another file in another location. If it is working you can accept answer.

Comment: It's working. How can grub be totally reinstalled?

Comment: If it is working, I would not reinstall. But newer users find the advanced mode of Boot-Repair easiest as it walks you thru  it. But you have to always boot live installer in correct mode for your system either always UEFI or always BIOS.