# Grub doesn't see kubuntu in multiboot after Windows 8.1 was re-installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu

I got a problem after Windows re-install, I can't set up grub properly - it doesn't detect Kubuntu, whatever I did.

At first, system & partitioning:
Kubuntu 17.10
Windows 8.1

Disks mode: GPT

- sda1 - don't know what it really is, Windows creates it automatically within installation.
- sda2 - EFI
- sda3 - unknown (Windows created this)
- sda4 - Windows
- sda5 - vfat /boot
- sda6 - luks - vg0 (root, swap)

So, I had Windows and Kubuntu 17.10 with manually tuned luks (Special Thanks to [Encrypted custom install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918021/encrypted-custom-install)).

Everything worked well, before I did Windows re-install and erased grub. 
I tried to chroot into broken system and re-install grub

/boot - sda5
/boot/efi - sda2

```
apt-get purge grub-common
apt-get install grub-common
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi /dev/sda

update-initramfs -k all -c
update-grub
```

Grub is installed to /dev/sda with no mistakes, but **update-grub** fetchs only Windows EFI loader and doesn't recognize Kubuntu.

How can I fix it without Kubuntu re-install?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried with this?: [RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Comment: All flavors of Ubuntu except Kubuntu use /EFI/ubuntu in the ESP. Kubuntu should have another folder /EFI/kubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/957914/dual-boot-14-04-17-04-lost-grub-menu/958220#958220