# update-grub command has no effect

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

After installing a Kubuntu on a second hard drive, it changed the boot order of my main hard drive GRUB and I can't change it back since.

**Any change to the grub configuration file (`/etc/default/grub`) applied with `update-grub` has no effect.**

The `update-grub` change the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file correctly, but does not modify any file in the `/boot/efi/` directory, while this should happen since the mounting point of my GRUB is `boot/efi`.

I thought it was due to `write` permission, but I checked, `root` has `write` permission over these files.

The output of the `sudo update-grub` command:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
Found Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) on /dev/sdb2
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Content of the `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

**EDIT, IMPORTANT:**

It seems like the GRUB is only affected by configuration at booting time by reading the configuration file. So, if I understand, mine is loading its configuration on the Kubuntu partition. But how can I change this behavior? This [question has already been asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296853/how-to-set-default-grub-configuration-file) but not correctly answered.

Comment: Related: [How can I reinstall GRUB to the EFI partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/831216/250300)

Comment: You do not have to chroot, but just boot into the install you want to be default and reinstall grub from there. The actual control file is /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg which is just 3 lines and a configfile entry to full grub.cfg in your install. You can edit that with correct UUID. See this for details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/957914/dual-boot-14-04-17-04-lost-grub-menu/958220#958220

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by executing the `grub-install` command, explanations:

As said before, **the GRUB is only affected by configuration at booting time by reading the configuration file**. The GRUB binaries store the path to this configuration file. In order to set the correct path to the desired configuration file, it is required to update these binaries.

I managed to do it very easily by executing the `sudo grub-install` command **from the OS where the desired configuration is stored** (the command does not required any additional parameters).

Now, the GRUB is affected by any change at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit your answer to expand it with specific details about what you did.

Comment: I'm just getting this: `grub-install: error: install device isn't specified.`

Comment: `grub-install` requires the device path, use `lsblk` to find your installation disk, the one with the `/` mount point.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem.  I have triple boot: windows 10, linux mint and ubuntu.  It broke after I update linux mint from 20.3 to 21.  I kept running update-grub in mint, it did show mint 21 detected (kernel 5.15.0-52) and said it updated.  But the boot stayed as mint 20 and failed to load (because old kernel had been removed).  ( I can temporarily updated it with "e" in grub menu.)

It turned out that grub that was effective was setup with ubuntu, which was installed before mint.  I logged into ubuntu and ran "update-grub".  And the grub menu was fixed.

Hope it might be useful for somebody.