# dual boot(grub?) problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I’ve got a question about the boot order. See I’m trying to set up a simple dualboot with ubuntu 16.04(server) on one ssd and 18.04(server) on the other.

In the grub the order is

```
16.04
16.04advanced mode
18.04
18.04advanced mode
```

When I log in to the 16.04 and edit grub,the GRUB_DEFAULT=0 means it will launch 16.04 on the next boot,but if I change it to GRUB_DEFAULT=2 it launches 18.04

Once in 18.04,if I change the line to GRUB_DEFAULT=0, it boots only 18.04(unless I manually pick 16.04),and no matter what order number I specify it still launches 18.04

Got any ideas what could help ?

Comment: Currently you use the boot-loader of your `16.04`. Changes in `/etc/default/grub` in your `18.04` will have no effect on the boot-loader of `16.04`, this boot-loader reads it's configuration from  your `16.04`.

Comment: Where and how should I edit the 16.04 grub once I'm already logged in the 18.04 ? I'm trying to set it up so that I could change between the two through ssh

Comment: Are your OS's installed in legacy mode or in EFI mode?

Comment: As far as I understand,UEFI

Comment: If it is UEFI boot, grub is in /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg with a 3 line configfile to load the full grub.cfg in your install. You can manually edit it to be your 18.04 install or do a full reinstall of grub from your 18.04 install which will also update that file and totally replace all other parts of grub. Save any configuration changes first if desired. Example grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu
https://askubuntu.com/questions/957914/dual-boot-14-04-17-04-lost-grub-menu/958220#958220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` in both systems (don't forget `sudo update-grub`).

Then install additional instances of grub to your ESP, from 16.04 run

```
sudo grub-install --bootloader-id=Server16.04
```

and from 18.04 run

```
sudo grub-install --bootloader-id=Server18.04
```

Check your boot-menu-entries with `efibootmgr -v`. Example:

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0005,0003
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,249ac0f6-d3e4-4b91-91d5-6e8d63c093c3,0x800,0x9a000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
Boot0001* US1804    HD(1,GPT,249ac0f6-d3e4-4b91-91d5-6e8d63c093c3,0x800,0x9a000)/File(\EFI\US1804\grubx64.efi)
Boot0002* US1604    HD(1,GPT,249ac0f6-d3e4-4b91-91d5-6e8d63c093c3,0x800,0x9a000)/File(\EFI\US1604\grubx64.efi)
Boot0003* UEFI OS   HD(1,GPT,249ac0f6-d3e4-4b91-91d5-6e8d63c093c3,0x800,0x9a000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
Boot0005* US1810    HD(1,GPT,249ac0f6-d3e4-4b91-91d5-6e8d63c093c3,0x800,0x9a000)/File(\EFI\US1810\shimx64.efi)
```

Now make use of EFI's next-boot feature with

```
efibootmgr -n XXXX
```

where XXXX is the hex-number of the desired boot entry. Example:

```
efibootmgr -n 5
```

will boot to 18.10 on next boot, so the only thing left is to reboot.