# Grub failure after removal of second system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu Server 23.10 on the computer with Kubuntu 23.10 on the second disk. After some time I deleted the second system, just formatted the disk and on Kubuntu I did update-grub. After restarting Grub showed me only minimal bash.... Of course I reinstalled Grub and everything works, but I don't understand where I went wrong. Someone can give me a hint?

I certainly did not format the boot partition either when installing the second system or when removing it.

Comment: The grub from Server was the leading one I think, so grub was looking for config's in the wrong no longer existing filesystem

Comment: Second install is normally the default. If you wanted other install as default, you boot into it and reinstall grub from it, before deleting second install. If UEFI as most systems are now, you can also just edit UUID & partition in the three line grub in the ESP. Example grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu
https://askubuntu.com/questions/957914/dual-boot-14-04-17-04-lost-grub-menu/958220#958220