How to change the boot order for 2 ubuntu systems sharing same Grub?
The efibootmgr is not showing 2 ubuntu system but the Grub GNU does show 2 ubuntu systems, how can I change the boot order to bring the second ubuntu higher on the order as it my primary system?

Easiest is just to boot into install you want to boot first & reinstall grub. sudo grub-install. That  uses ESP mount in fstab as default & everything else is default. But it will change the UUID in /EFI/ubuntu/grub to use UUID of current install. You can manually edit that file also. Major update to grub will also do same thing, so if second install updates you may have to repeat fix. https://askubuntu.com/questions/957914/dual-boot-14-04-17-04-lost-grub-menu/958220#958220

Hey thanks buddy, it did work!!.
